# Passing Windows file as argument in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

I want to know , what path should i Enter in Eclipse(run Configurations) for passing a windows file as arguments. For ex : My file path is  C:\Users\sa\Documents\file.conf .
Thanks in advance

Comment: If that is the path then that is what you specify. It is not clear what your problem is here. Please [edit] your question and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put path to your file into RunConfigurations > Arguments > Program arguments as variable. There is a good practice to keep files in /resource folder.